# Do we use 'with' or 'to' with 'proportionally'?

Tags: word-choice, difference

> The temperature increases proportionally to/with pressure

I found [some](https://www.englishforums.com/English/DoesSentenceSoundRightIncreaseLack/plghx/post.htm) [forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/proportional-proportionally.1501051/) that used 'to' instead of 'with'. I have heard the adjective 'proportional' used with 'to', as '*X is proportional to Y*'.

But when it comes to the adverb, I feel 'with' sounds better. But Google search (even though both expressions yield thousands of results, '[to](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=increases%20proportionally%20to%20or%20with&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&ei=DeVZWeLYDPDx8AfMwZ2wBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22proportionally%20to%22)' is more commonly used than '[with](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=increases%20proportionally%20to%20or%20with&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gfe_rd=cr&ei=DeVZWeLYDPDx8AfMwZ2wBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22proportionally%20with%22)') and [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proportionally%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cproportionally%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bproportionally%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20more%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20greater%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20increased%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20less%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20larger%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20diminished%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20large%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bproportionally%20great%3B%2Cc0) disagrees with me. Any help?

Comment: You can resolve the question by saying instead: _"The temperature increases **in proportion to** pressure..."_ The adverb is inelegant here anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OED has, for the phrase *in proportion*:

> in (also *†for, †of, †with*) proportion: in a known or specific proportion *to* something else, or as something else varies; proportionately.

The inference is that the phrase *in proportion* takes the preposition *to.* This usage is supported by numerous examples, e.g.:

> 1990   *Taxation & Environmental Policy* (Inst. Fiscal Stud.) Comm. No. 19. 2   Taxing those who damage the environment in proportion to the damage they do.

The OED has, for the adjective *proportional*:

> **3**. *Math.* That is in proportion; (of two or more pairs of quantities) having the same ratio.

Numerous supporting examples indicate that the adjective takes the preposition *to*, e.g:

> 1991   C. A. Ronan *Nat. Hist. Universe* 18/1 (*caption*)    In Euclidean space, a circle's area is proportional to the square of its radius.

It would be expected that an adverb whose root adjective takes the preposition *to* would take the same preposition; yet the OED *also* has, for the adverb *proportionally*:

> a. In a proportional manner or degree; in (due) proportion; correspondingly.

This usage is supported by numerous examples in which the adverb takes the preposition *with*, e.g.:

> 1960   A. H. Benade *Horns, Strings, & Harmony* vi. 110   The frequency of a string rises proportionally with the square root of the tension.

We are clearly on our own here, in the vast unfettered realm that is the living language. The OED would seem to have us use *with*, but there is no definitive statement to that effect. In the cited OED example provided for the adverb, it modifies the verb *rise*, which agrees in effect with the verb *increase* in your example. With a slight preference for *with*, I would choose the preposition that sounds best to me; either *to* or *with* will be understood by an English-speaking reader.

Answer (score 3):

Both prepositions "**to**" and "**with**" work here, although they have a different meaning.

The most common usage of "**proportionally to**" is within the scope of *comparing something of one thing to something of another* and means "**to a proportionate degree**" ([Definition in Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proportionally)):

- Your salary will rise **proportionally to** your workload. *(Compare the rise of salary to the amount of workload)*
- Health problems increased **proportionally to** the number of hours worked. *(Compare amount of health problems to the number of hours worked)*

The most common usage of "**proportionally with**" is within the scope of either *by means of something* or *due to the change of something*:

- Sevoflurane consumption does not decrease **proportionally with** fresh gas flows reduction. *(A change in fresh gas flows reduction doesn't proportionally decrees Sevoflurane consumption)*
- Resizing a figure **proportionally with** handles. *(Resizing a figure proportionally by means of handles)*
- Does expressive timing in music performance scale **proportionally with** tempo? *(Does the change of tempo proportionally scale the expressive timing in music?)*

Comment: "proptional(ly) to" is a set phrase. The examples of "proportionally with" are misleading, since the "with" is part of the next phrase, not joined to "proportionally". You could just as well (correctly) say "Resizing a figure proportionally using handles" or ".. decrease proportionally when fresh gas flows reduce" but those examples don't say anything general about how to use the phrases "proportionally using" or "proportionally when." - such "phrases" don't exist.